# Search for strings from df2.col2 as substrings in df1.col1 and replace them with strings from df2.col1

Tags: python-3.x, str-replace

Haven not been able to get the desired result:

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Address":['1024 FRANCIS CIRC', '2077 JOHNSON CLF', '1099 S ARLINGTON RDGE ROAD']})
```

I have a second dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Address_Type":['CIRCLE','CIRCLE','CLIFF','RIDGE','RIDGE'],
"Abbreviation":['CIR','CIRC','CLF','RDG','RDGE']})
```

I'd like to search for strings in df2.Abbreviation in df1.Address and if found, change it to the corresponding string in df2.Address_Type.

The result I'd like to see is:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame("Address":['1024 FRANCIS CIRCLE', '2077 JOHNSON CLIFF', '1099 S ARLINGTON RIDGE ROAD']})
```

Been trying lambda function and lambda function with function calls, but no cigar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(df1['Address'])):

    str_item = df1['Address'].iloc[i].split( )

    for j in range(len(str_item)):

        index_row = df2.loc[df2['Abbreviation'] == '{}'.format(str_item[j])].index.values.astype(int)

    if index_row > 0:

        str_item[j] = df2['Address_Type'].iloc[index_row].values[0]

    str_new = ' '.join(str_item)

   df1['Address'].iloc[i] = str_new
```